# Program is outputing answer for coin toss even if the user chose card

Tags: python

```
def program():
    print ("please make sure your answer is spelt correctly")
    print ('Start program')
    choice = input("please select either a card or coin?") 


    if choice == "COIN" or "coin" or "Coin":  
        print ("you will now be given heads or tails")   


    import random

    higher_value = 2
    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

    if final_value == 1:
        print ("Heads")

    elif final_value == 2:
        print ("Tails")
        #CARD
    else:                                    
        if choice == "Card" or "card" or "CARD":
            print("you will now be given a number for; number,suit")


    import random
    higher_value = 13
    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

    if final_value == 1:
               print ("ace")

    if final_value == 2:
               print ("2")
    if final_value == 3:
               print ("3")
    if final_value == 4:
               print ("4")
    if final_value == 5:
               print ("5")
    if final_value == 6:
               print ("6")
    if final_value == 7:
               print ("7")
    if final_value == 8:
               print ("8")
    if final_value == 9:
               print ("9")
    if final_value == 10:
               print ("10")  
    if final_value == 11:
               print ("Jack")
    if final_value == 12:
               print ("Queen")
    if final_value == 13:
               print ("King")


    import random

    higher_value = 4
    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

    if final_value == 1:
               print ("Hearts")
    if final_value == 2:
               print ("Clubs")
    if final_value == 3:
               print ("Spades")
    if final_value == 4:
               print ("Diamonds")
    #REPEAT LOOP
    flag = True
    while flag:
        program()
        flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [y/n]') == 'y'    
    print ("The program will now terminate.")    
    print ("Have a good day")
```

I am currently trying to separate the two parts of the program this is due to the fact that if I input card it will out put the results of coin toss and card pick this is quite frustrating. I can't see a reason why this may be happening so could someone please fix this for me, thanks :)

Comment: You should write some functions.

Comment: like what, I dunno what functions to use

Answer (score 1):

You have to correctly indent this part:

```
import random

higher_value = 2
lower_value = 1
final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

if final_value == 1:
    print ("Heads")

elif final_value == 2:
    print ("Tails")
```

It must have the same indentation as `print ("you will now be given heads or tails")`, or else the interpreter will assume it exists outside the if statement

In the same manner you have to indent everything below `print("you will now be given a number for; number,suit")` correctly

Remember that python is different than other languages in the way that you do not use curly braces or begin..end statements to show a block of code. Rather the interpreter understands blocks of code through indentation, so you have to be careful with it.

EDIT: To further explain it, you must understand the difference of the following pieces of code:

```
i=1
j=2

if i==1: 
    print i
    if j==10:
        print j
else:            #<--- this corresponds to if i==1:
    print j
```

This will print 1

However, by just changing the indentation:

```
i=1
j=2

if i==1:
    print i
    if j==10:
        print j
    else:        #<--- now this corresponds to if j==10:
        print j
```

This will print 1 2

EDIT 2:

```
if choice == "COIN" or "coin" or "Coin":
```

This must be changed to

```
if choice == "COIN" or choice == "coin" or choice == "Coin":
```

Or else it will always evaluate to true

In the same manner change : `if choice == "Card" or "card" or "CARD":`

EDIT 3: 
This works for me

```
import random

def main():
  print ("please make sure your answer is spelt correctly")
  print ('Start program')
  choice = input("please select either a card or coin?")
  if choice == "COIN" or choice == "coin" or choice == "Coin":  
    print ("you will now be given heads or tails")
    higher_value = 2
    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)
    if final_value == 1:
      print ("Heads")
    elif final_value == 2:
      print ("Tails")
#CARD
  else: 
    if choice == "Card" or choice == "card" or choice == "CARD":
      print("you will now be given a number for; number,suit")

      higher_value = 13
      lower_value = 1
      final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

      if final_value == 1:
       print ("ace")
      if final_value == 2:
        print ("2")
      if final_value == 3:
        print ("3")
      if final_value == 4:
        print ("4")
      if final_value == 5:
        print ("5")
      if final_value == 6:
        print ("6")
      if final_value == 7:
        print ("7")
      if final_value == 8:
        print ("8")
      if final_value == 9:
        print ("9")
      if final_value == 10:
        print ("10")  
      if final_value == 11:
        print ("Jack")
      if final_value == 12:
        print ("Queen")
      if final_value == 13:
        print ("King")
      higher_value = 4
      lower_value = 1
      final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

      if final_value == 1:
        print ("Hearts")
      if final_value == 2:
        print ("Clubs")
      if final_value == 3:
        print ("Spades")
      if final_value == 4:
        print ("Diamonds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: this is confusing me I have used else statements so separate the coin and card options but it continues to produce results for both???

Comment: The `else` statement is not enough without the correct indentation, see my edit

Comment: I still don't understand can you just send me a corrected statement or program please, thanks.

Comment: See my Edit 2 as well, most probably that is your problem after you correct the indentation

Comment: it doesn't work it still produces results for both, coin and card

Comment: My guess is your indentation is still not correct. Check my Edit 3 for a working code